# SignUp is not permitted for this user pool aws cognito message

Tags: amazon-cognito

i have only allowed administrators to create users, so when a user tries to sign up it gives this message, which is working fine. But i want to customize this error message. From where in the aws cognito i can change that to something more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal exception message that you cannot change.

What you can do instead, is to catch this exception and re-throw your own with any custom message you like. Something like:

```
try {
    apiClinet->SignUp()
} catch (NotAuthorizedException e) {
    throw new MyOwnCustomException('Any message you like')
}
```